# htaccess redirect with GET request

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Following is my htaccess:

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /Forum URIs
RewriteRule ^Forum/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?seo=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?id=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?seo=$2 [L,QSA] 

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Above codes are working fine except for following two scenario:

1. .php extension is not getting removed for pages under 'Forum' directory. Their is no GET request in these pages. If I remove the condition for Forum above then gives 404 error  Forum/.php not found.
2. Also, .php extension is not getting removed for pages where GET request variable is other than 'seo'.
3. URL with 'seo' as GET variable are converting into SEO friendly but GET request with other variables like 'id' or 'rg=&vp=&da=' are not working. I have added additional rules (as for seo) for the same but still no impact.

Kindly advise.

Comment: You need to provide lot more details like which URL in `/forum/` isn't working and is there any .htaccess in `/forum/` directory as well? What should be the pretty URL for `?rg=&vp=&da=` and `?id=` etc.

Comment: 1. Forum is a folder and any .php files under this folder is not removing .php extension 2. I only have .htaccess in root folder. 3. I have one page where GET request is based on 'seo' as well as 'popular' and 'rg=&vp=&da='. Issue is that only one such condition is working. Codes for other conditions aren't working. E.g. http://example.com/test/page.php?seo=abc-def is  working fine as http://example.com/test/page/abc-def but other like http://example.com/test/page.php?popular=efg-hik-abc is not coming like http://example.com/test/page/efg-hik-abc and so on for other "rg=&vp=&da= etc...

Comment: The way your code is you have `/abc` loading `/page.php?seo=abc` therefore you **cannot** have `/xyz` to load `/page.php?popular=abc`. It is better to just translate every query string into slash like: ` example.com/test/page/seo/abc-def/` and example.com/test/page/popular/xyz/` etc as pretty URL scheme.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response... this solution will not work for me. However, what about .php extension not going away for pages in Forum folder?

Comment: For `forum` `.php` issue I can post an answer if you want.

Comment: Anubhav...that will be a great help. can I share the exact website wherein you can look into the above 3 issues and may be above to offer a resolution. I have jsut sent the exact website address via Linkedin. Looking forward for your help to resolve these issues. Rgds,

Comment: sent details via Linkedin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)\.php\?seo=([^&\s]+)(?:&(\S+))? [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2?%3 [R,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)\.php(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?id=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?seo=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This results into 404 error for all pages under 'Forum' directory as example.com/Forum/.php not found

Comment: More errors now: The requested URL /Forum.php was not found on this server. Also, some of others URL also throwing 404 errors.

Comment: Which Forum URL didn't work? Is this .htaccess still in DocumentRoot? Yes I got your LinkedIn message.

Comment: I have only one htaccess and that is in root folder only. Also, I have shared the exact links and folder names in msg.

Comment: But I didn't see any `/Forum/` links there.

Comment: Anubhav... forum was an example... as stated exact folder name is 'Hotels'

Comment: Thank you Anubhava for posting above codes. This has resolved php extension removal issue. Is there any way to now get Issue#1 and Issue#2 resolved?

Comment: As I commented for those issues you will need to rethink your SEO strategy. Since a URL like `/abc` cannot load both `/page.php?seo=abc` and `/page.php?popular=abc`

Comment: Ok...just noticed one more issue. With the above codes in place..I am experiencing issue with one page 'List.php' where pagination is in place. Click to next page does not load next page here. In actual URL clicking adds &page=[page number] to existing url like example.com/test/list.php?var1=abc becomes example.com/test/list.php?var1=abc&page=2

Comment: With above pretty URL rule what URL are you seeing in your browser after clicking on next page and what behavior do you exepect?

Comment: example.com/test/var1value before and after clicking the next page. page not moving to next page. Ideally page should move next or previous and url should look like: example.com/test/var1value/pagenumber

Comment: Hmmm that will be lot of extra code. I will update in few hours after reaching home.

Comment: I tried but rules were conflicting with each other. I think it would be better to leave `example.com/test/list.php?var1=abc&page=2` unchanged with **some modifications in the rule** (that I can make).

Comment: unchanged means url with query string?... if that is the case then we are only removing .php extension..right? If that is the case then I may just want to get rid of rewriting as that is of no use. However, if exiting rewritten url extended to support pagination (may not look like .../varvalue1/pagnumber but may be like ....varvalue1&page=2) will be fine

Comment: Yes that might be possible, let me tweak the rules.

Comment: This results into example.com/test/var1value%20HTTP/1.1 on entire website and not just on List page and gives 404 error

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I have been able to resolved the issue and now everything working fine except Issue#1 and 2. Thank you very much for your support which helped me to move in the right direction. You are really a champ! If you are in a position to offer any alternate solution which can help me in getting two left out issues resolved, that'll be great help from your side. Once again, thank you for your time, expertise and resolution offered. WOW...

Comment: You're most welcome. I just came online. So except pagination everything is working fine? Or is there any other issue also?

Comment: Even pagination is working fine now (don't know how to post those working codes here). The only issues left out now to get SEO friendly url for 'popular' and 'rg=vtp=cpt=' variables on the List page which you said would require different methodology. Is there any other way to handle these two items (may be some different conditions and rules)

Comment: Oh ok that one is not possible unless you change pretty URL scheme as I suggested earlier.